# Help Solving Fraction Math Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Im stumped by this question on a practice ACT math test:

> If $\frac 1x + \frac 1y = \frac 1z$ then $z =$?

The correct answer is $\frac {xy}{x + y}$.

How do you arrive at this answer? I don't know how to even begin with this problem.

Comment: *Hint:*

$$\frac 1x + \frac 1y = \frac{y + x}{xy}$$

See what to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply both sides of the expression $\frac {1}{x} + \frac {1}{y} = \frac {1}{z}$ by the number $xyz$.

So you get $\frac {xyz}{x} + \frac {xyz}{y} = \frac {xyz}{z}$, which is, after cancelling, equal to $yz+xz=xy$.

Now, $yz+xz=z(x+y)=xy$.

Divide $z(x+y)=xy$ with $(x+y)$ to obtain $z= \frac {xy}{x+y}$.

Answer (score 0):

Adding up the two fractions in the usual way leads to
$$\frac1x+\frac1y=\frac{y}{xy}+\frac{x}{xy}=\frac{x+y}{xy}.$$
Now solving $\tfrac{x+y}{xy}=\tfrac1z$ gives us
$$z=\frac{xy}{x+y}.$$

Comment: What do you mean by adding up the two fractions in the usual way?

Comment: How would you add up $\tfrac{1}{3}+\tfrac{1}{5}$, for example?

Comment: I would find a common denominator $15$ and convert each fraction to have that denominator by doing $\frac {1 * 5}{3 * 5} + \frac {1 * 3}{5 * 3}$ then we get $\frac {5}{15} + \frac {3}{15}$ and the answer $\frac {8}{15} $ I now see how this applies to the above problem by getting the same denominators. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Multiply the equation by $xyz$
2. Move all values with $z$ on one side of the equation.
3. Factor out $z$. You get an expression like $A\cdot z = B$ where $A$ and $B$ are some expression.
4. Divide the equation by $A$.